# How to create two tables in SQLite and use the insertData for the two?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

I am developing a browser and created a table to save the favorites, now I intend to create the history, I created a new table but the error, in logCat says that the table does not exist, can anyone help me?

```
    package br.wds.yourbrowser;

import android.content.*;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.support.v4.view.*;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="favoritos.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="favoritos";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_TWO="historicos";
        public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="NAME";
    public static final String COL_3="LINK";   
    public static final String COL_HIS_1="PAGE";
    public static final String COL_HIS_2="URL";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "(" + "_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, LINK TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_TWO+ "(" + "_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PAGE TEXT, URL TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME_TWO);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String link, String page, String url)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try{
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_2, name);
        cv.put(COL_3, link);

       final long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);

        ContentValues cvs = new ContentValues();
        cvs.put(COL_HIS_1, page);
        cvs.put(COL_HIS_2, url);

     final   long re = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_TWO,null,cvs);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.close();


        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        }
            finally{
            db.endTransaction();
        }       
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an english language site.  Try pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Diego: to make it easy, please write in english language. You will get more help if everybody understands your question. If you translate it, your question will be reopened.

Comment: I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @diego: If you make any changes on your database structure or table structure, you have to delete it. So delete the app from your device and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the method onUpgrade is dropping the tables and you are not creating them again with the new structure. So, you could either drop them and recreate onUpgrade, but will lose the data or use the sql command ALTER TABLE to add columns or whatever changes you would like. I hope this helps.